# Can't install netmiko or paramiko

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm at wits end, been trying to install netmiko and paramiko all day with no luck on Windows 10 with Python version 3.8.0b3. Tried it earlier with 3.7.4 with no luck either.

I run the following command:

```
python -m pip install netmiko --user
```

and get the following error:

```
 Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-sbe5z7zj\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
```

Answer (score 0):

So after much consternation, I found the problem, I uninstalled python ran the customer installer didn't install idle and "**select for all users**" so that it put it in c:\program files\python37 instead of the C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages, adjusted the environment variables and it then was able complete pip install netmiko --user.

I hope this helps someone else.